# Redirect link to map route

Tags: reactjs, redux

I want to Redirect to admin home screen after hitting some backend service url irrespective of the response.

I have used Redirect of react-router-dom module to achieve this task. But I am not getting any screen.

**User Login component :**

```
  handleSubmit = async event => {
  event.preventDefault();

  const user = {
    email: this.state.email,
    password: this.state.password
  };
  await this.props.dispatch(authActiokns.authenticate(user.email, user.password));
  return <Redirect exact to="/adminHome" />;
}
```

**Route component :**

```
{
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          {
            loggedIn
            ? <Route exact path="/adminHome" component={AdminHome}></Route>
            : <Route exact path="/" component={Login}></Route>
          }
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { loggedIn: authSelectors.getLoginDetails(state).loggedIn }
}
```

Basically I want user to show **Admin component** after logged in but only using the Route. But here is another part of this problem I should not go back to **login screen** after successfully logged in except user logs out manually. So I want to **redirect** user to admin home if press back button and after logout if he press forward button I want user to **remain** on login screen. Though I have written a logic for this previously it was working but not in this case.

Comment: Call to `<Redirect>` should be inside render method conditionally as it is a component.

Comment: yeah @tarzenchugh is right. Please try that